# Structure variable initialization/definition in one go after variable declaration is done

Tags: c, structure, definition, redefinition

Can we define structure variable after its declaration or definition in one go? All together in single braces like

```
asd = {21,'H'};
```

Any particular reason if it cannot be done, since it can be defined in same line where it is being declared e.g.: `struct asd = {21,'H'};` ?

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
}asd;  

asd = {21,'H'};   // error: expected an expression
```

Asked for C programming.

Comment: Because aggregate initialization is different from assignment.

Comment: fyi: `auto asd = {21,'H'};` doesn't work.  `auto asd = {21,22};` does compile, but does not do what you are asking for.

Comment: Could you pick a language please. c isn't c++ isn't c.

Comment: Why was this retagged to just C, this invalidates answers here

Comment: Added c++ again, got confused I thought guy above meant to pick one and remove other. Instead he was asking me for which language I wanted the answer or asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit type cast is required:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
} asd;  

asd = (struct test){21,'H'};
```

This code is roughly equivalent to the following one:

```
const struct test initialiser = {21,'H'};
... 
asd = initialiser;
```

The difference is that the compiler has an option to optimise the assignment of a value to the `asd` variable using assembler instructions with immediate values when such optimisation is more efficient than const structure copy initialisation.

As a 'side' effect this syntax is valid in both `C` and `C++`

Comment: @2501 I did not know it has a specific name. Could you tell me, please?

Comment: @nathanoliver 1. Can same thing could be done for struct asd[5]; after its declaration ? Not like *(asd + 3) = (struct tt){ -2, '\0' }; But for all elements of array as together in one line.  2. Can all normal arrays like int ary[5] = {1,22,31,231,5}; can be done after its declared ? eg: ary = (int){1,22,31,231,5};

Comment: @Lpdnn unfortunatelly no, arrays can't be assigned this way. The only workaround is to make an array a member of a struct;

Comment: What about structure arrays assigned all together? struct asd[5]; Can you give me a example of what you mean by making an  array a member of a struct for workaround?

Comment: @lpdnn regardless of the array item type, array can't be assigned a value apart from initialiser used in array declaration. You have to use memcpy or other means, i.e. assign a value to an array[index] in a loop or whatever else

Comment: struct test {  int asd[5]; }a;
 a = (struct test){ 1, 66, 99, 4, 5 }; Seemed to work but cannot start from any particular element gives error. hf

Answer (score 2):

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
}asd;
```

Is the definition of the `struct` `test` and the variable `asd` of type `test`.  At the `;` you now have a default constructed object called `asd`.  When you try to do

```
asd = {21, 'H'};
```

You are trying to assign to `asd` and braced list which will not work since it does not have an assignment operator that takes a initialization list.

You can either initialize `asd` when you declare it like

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
}asd = {21, 'H'};
```

or do the assignment like

```
asd = (struct test){21, 'H'};
```

If you do chose to use assignment do note that it must be done inside a function and not in the global space.

Comment: The assignment needs to be in main, since otherwise, you get this error: `error: 'asd' does not name a type`

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Added about that.

Comment: @Lpdnn I was using the C++ syntax.  I updated the answer with the C syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As @CaptainOblivious mentioned:

> –aggregate initialization is different from assignment.

What this means, is that you cant use aggregate initialization in assignment for aggregate objects later, without being explicit or separate, like this:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
}asd; 
int main() {asd.a = 21; asd.b = 'H'}
```

An alternative thing to do would being explicit later (this needs to be done in main, or in another code block, or you get an error (`asd does not name a type`)):

```
asd = test{21,'H'}
```

Another thing you can do is this:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
}asd = {21,'H'};
```

Both of the above would work as well, as seen here:
<kbd>[Live Example](http://cpp.sh/7jmk2)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

If you are defining a variable of that type you must include the `struct` part, like `struct asd`. But this definition and initialisation all together works just fine.

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    char b;
} asd = { 21, 'H'};
```

Comment: OP asked if the definition and intialisation can be done in one go, and my answer shows that it can. Thanks for the lovely downvote.  If you know better, please share your knowledge, so we may all benefit.